# Location of files in magento

Tags: magento

I need to find out the location of file in block `type` and `name` tag

```
<vendors_sales_order_index>
  <reference name="content">
    <block type="vendorssales/vendor_sales_order" name="vendor.order.list" />
  </reference>
</vendors_sales_order_index>
```

Above is the xml snippet. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes

It depends on your project setup: store views and layout config. By the way, what version of Magento are you using?

Cheers!